# When to use WinJS.Navigation.state versus options

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I know that I can use `WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/page2/page2.html", someData)` to navigate to a page passing data. From the destination page, I can then access `someData` by either accessing `options` in the ready function or by accessing `WinJS.Navigation.state`. Which options should I be choosing and when??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State is going to be different when going "back"; this will be any state that you've placed on the history information as the user interacts with the page (Scrolling, selection, entered text etc.).

Options is used when navigating to a new page; they're options coming from somewhere else to enable you to make sure that the right things are **initially** selected.